# Angular Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to turn my bootstrap navbar into an angular element so that I can change the attributes in the controller rather than rewriting every page. The navbar won't show though and it's not throwing any errors

### HTML call

```
 <body ng-app="appHeaderApp">
  <div class="main" ng-controller="appHeaderController">
  <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
  <app-header info="tab"></app-header>
  </div>
```

### appHeaderApp

```
var app = angular.module("appHeaderApp", []);
```

### appHeaderController

```
app.controller('appHeaderController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
  $scope.myNavTabs = [
{ 
    tab1: 'link',
  tab2: 'more links',
  tab3: 'different link',
  tab4: 'another link',
  tab5: 'last link'
}
 ];
   /*$scope.returnEvents = function(index) { 
  'I have been in,' + $scope.myinfo[index].userEvents; 
 };*/
 }]);
```

### headerjs.html

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-   toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="active"><a href="#"> {{info.tab1}} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"> {{info.tab2}} </a></li>
           <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> {{info.tab3}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="#"> {{info.tab4}} </a></li>
                 <!-- put the login form here -->
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
```

### appHeader.js

```
app.directive('appHeader', function() { 
 return { 
restrict: 'E', 
scope: { 
  info: '=' 
}, 
templateUrl: 'js/directives/headerjs.html' 
   }; 
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-repeat` should have `<div ng-repeat="tab in myNavTabs">` instead of tabs since you have assigned your array to $scope.myNavTabs and not $scope.tabs.

---

```
$scope.myNavTabs = [
{ 
    tab1: 'link',
  tab2: 'more links',
  tab3: 'different link',
  tab4: 'another link',
  tab5: 'last link'
}
 ];
```

Comment: i did that and it is still not rendering but it is throwing this error now angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: Can you put a console.log inside your appHeaderController and check if its working or not.

Comment: okay so I put the console.log in there and nothing it printing to the console

Comment: Then maybe there is something wrong with your angular app. Is your angularjs script being loaded before your app.js ? Can you put up your code on plunkr so that it is easier to identify the problem.

Comment: I can't see where you have included your custom scripts. Please include these and try <script src="appHeaderApp.js"></script>
<script src="appHeaderController.js"></script>

Comment: I updated the code on plunker and it's throwing no errors but isn't logging

Comment: You were having an extra ng-app and ng-controller for 'profile' and you did not include your scripts in your index.html. The directive template url was also incorrect.

Comment: So I can't have multiple apps then? They have to be grouped under one app

Comment: You can have multiple apps. But you need to create angular.module for each ng-app. Also, why would you need to add an ng-app to the meta tag ?